# Why does my oracle date field does not fall within the queried range?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this sql query :

```
select email_id, to_char(last_update_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mi:ss') 
from profile_table
where last_update_date < sysdate and
      last_update_date > sysdate -1;
```

Which returns result

> ```
>                 EMAIL_ID   TO_CHAR(last_update_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mi:ss')
> ------------------------   ------------------------------------------------
>        email_007@abc.com                                2017-03-28 12:00:04
>        nachppx@gmail.com                                2017-03-28 03:45:26
>        QM_SFGD@yahoo.com                                2017-03-29 08:24:12
> j.w.booth@rocketmail.com                                2017-03-29 11:16:00
> ```

However, I am pretty sure that that query is missing record that should be within that 'where' range, because when I issue this :

```
select email_id, to_char(last_update_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mi:ss')
from profile_table
where email_id = 'kgunash@gmail.com'
```

it returns

> ```
>                 EMAIL_ID   TO_CHAR(last_update_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mi:ss')
> ------------------------   ------------------------------------------------
>        kgunash@gmail.com                                2017-03-29 05:53:33
> ```

My sysdate during execution is as below :

```
select to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'), to_char(sysdate-1,'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')
from dual
```

> ```
> TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')   TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
> -------------------------------------   ---------------------------------------
>                   2017-03-29 11:12:19                       2017-03-28 11:12:19
> ```

Obviously **2017-03-29 05:53:33** should fall between **2017-03-29 11:12:19** and **2017-03-28 11:12:19**. Anyone got any idea what's going on?

Comment: Use `hh24` for the time format please, or the am/pm indicator otherwise all your times are ambiguous

Comment: That's it. @Mat solves it. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output uses 12 hour clock without AM/PM modifier. If the missing record is stamped `2017-03-29 05:53:33 PM` is in PM then it would be later than `2017-03-29 11:12:19 AM` and so correctly excluded from your result set.

Easiest way to check would be to use `HH24` format mask when displaying the dates.